# How do I test my three.js project on iPhone

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I created a new AR project, it's pretty simple, the user enters the website and has some AR stuff with their phone camera. The only problem is I don't know how to test my website on iPhone every time I add new code, for now I have an online free hosting and I just upload my changes there, but it's too time consuming. Is there a way to have my website directly on my iPhone?

Comment: use a local web server. Either a NAS with an integrated web server or a virtual web server such as XAMPP. Then you can simply develop on the web server directly and do not need to copy files for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with Live Server extension on a PC connected to a wireless LAN.

Live Server serves the website you're developing on a port (e.g. 5500) of your computer.

I write code on PC, launch Live Server, and from my phone (connected to the same wireless LAN) I browse to my PC IP adress on local Wireless LAN, followed by the port number (something like http://192.186.1.161:5500), and I can use the web app on my phone. Live Server has live reload: every time I modify some file on VSCode, the web page is reloaded on the (phone or PC) browser, showing the updated version.

For AR web app you probably have to serve it on secure (https) connection: Live Server [can do this](https://github.com/webisora/vscode-liveserver-https), but you have to [create your own SSL certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-generate-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-using-openssl). I used the openssl executable that comes with git.

Even if you don't use VSCode, there are many server applications that you can run on your PC and do the same thing.